# Tell Emacs to use always the same browser

Tags: html, web-browser

In my experience `xhtml-mode`'s `browse-url-of-buffer` command uses different browsers depending, I guess, on the different desktop environments (or on their absence sometimes).

My question, how can I tell Emacs to use always the same browser, desktop environment notwithstanding?

Bonus points :-) for the details of the Emacs-environment interaction that leads to `browse-url-of-buffer` calling a specific browser...

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `browse-url-browser-function`; you can use it to specify various functions, including `browse-url-firefox`, `browse-url-chromium`, `browse-url-w3` & many more — you can even write your own, if you feel like it.

You can find this sort of thing out for yourself by running e.g. `C-h f browse-url-of-buffer`, and then clicking on the `browse-url.el` link, which will take you to the definition of `browse-url-browser-function`; you can see at the end that it calls `(browse-url-of-file file-name)`; if you type M-. on `browse-url-of-file` you'll be taken to *its* definition and see from its docstring that it calls `browse-url`; *its* docstring discusses `browse-url-browser-function` and more.

You can also do `C-h a browse-url` to see stuff apropos to browsing URLs; there's a ton of stuff there.